# Running Lucene IndexWriter in a Stateless EJB?

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, lucene, singleton, ejb

I have a question about how to use the Lucene IndexWriter in an EJB Container.

In the past I run into a problem with Lucene because of a bad implementation of my own Java POJO class which wrapped a Lucene IndexWriter. My code was not thread-save. For that reason I decided to put all the code, which creates the indexWriter and updates the lucene index, into a @Singleton Stateless Session EJB. This was to make sure, that the IndexWriter is only accessed from one thread at one time. This works fine.

But my question is now - was this really necessary?
I would prefer to put my code, which adds a document into my lucene index, into a stateless session EJB. So that several instances of my EJB can work in parallel to add new documents into the index.

Is this possible or must the code, to create a new Lucene index writer, be run only in one thread at one time?
My code looks something like this:

```java
public boolean updateDocument(MyDocument data) throws Exception {
    Directory indexDir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDirectoryPath));
    IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig;
    indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LATEST,
                (Analyzer) Class.forName("org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.ClassicAnalyzer").newInstance());
    indexWriterConfig.setWriteLockTimeout(10000);
    IndexWriter myLuceneWriter = new IndexWriter(indexDir, indexWriterConfig);
    // update document...   
    ....
}
```

Comment: It looks to me that your question has little to do with JavaEE or EJB. The issue is whether two instances of IndexWriter can work together in parallel from two different threads, configured the way they are. Here is a link which is perhaps relevant http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ParallelIncrementalIndexing.

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right. I will take a look at this.